# Failed to read row 0, column 4 from CursorWindow, which has 1 row and 4 columns

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to make an SQLite database and all seems okay until I add "profileWeight" in the list. I have tried to look into other samples but all are different from mine. Can anybody help me with this. The code for my DBController.java is as below:

```
public class DBController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String LOGCAT = null;

public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
    super(applicationcontext, "profiledatabase.db", null, 1);
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE profiles ( profileId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, profileName TEXT, "
            + "profileDOB DATE, profileSex TEXT, profileWeight TEXT)";
    database.execSQL(query);
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "profiles Created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old,
        int current_version) {
    String query;
    query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS profiles";
    database.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(database);
}

public void insertProfile(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("profileName", queryValues.get("profileName"));
    values.put("profileDOB", queryValues.get("profileDOB"));
    values.put("profileSex", queryValues.get("profileSex"));
    values.put("profileWeight", queryValues.get("profileWeight"));

    database.insert("profiles", null, values);
    database.close();
}

public int updateProfile(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("profileName", queryValues.get("profileName"));
    values.put("profileDOB", queryValues.get("profileDOB"));
    values.put("profileSex", queryValues.get("profileSex"));    
    values.put("profileWeight", queryValues.get("profileWeight"));      

    return database.update("profiles", values, "profileId" + " = ?",
            new String[] { queryValues.get("profileId")});
    // String updateQuery =
    // "Update  words set txtWord='"+word+"' where txtWord='"+ oldWord +"'";
    // Log.d(LOGCAT,updateQuery);
    // database.rawQuery(updateQuery, null);
    // return database.update("words", values, "txtWord  = ?", new String[]
    // { word });
}

public void deleteProfile(String id) {
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "delete");
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM profiles where profileId='" + id
            + "'";
    Log.d("query", deleteQuery);
    database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllProfiles() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM profiles";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            profileMap.put("profileId", cursor.getString(0));
            profileMap.put("profileName", cursor.getString(1));
            profileMap.put("profileDOB", cursor.getString(2));
            profileMap.put("profileSex", cursor.getString(3));
            profileMap.put("profileWeight", cursor.getString(4));

            wordList.add(profileMap);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return wordList;
}

public HashMap<String, String> getProfileInfo(String id) {
    HashMap<String, String> wordList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM profiles where profileId='" + id
            + "'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            wordList.put("profileId", cursor.getString(0));             
            wordList.put("profileName", cursor.getString(1));
            wordList.put("profileDOB", cursor.getString(2));
            wordList.put("profileSex", cursor.getString(3));    
            wordList.put("profileWeight", cursor.getString(4));                 

            // wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return wordList;
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Column indexes start from 0. You're requesting index 4 (5th element) from a cursor that only has 4 columns. That's the explanation for the exception.

Why `SELECT *` from a 5-column table returns only 4 columns: You recently added another column, you'll need to ensure the database file is reflected with this change. Some options:

- Remove the old database file: e.g. uninstall the app. This ensures that your database helper `onCreate()` is run again to create a new database from scratch.
- Increase the database version `1` you pass to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` `super` constructor. Since the file on disk is version 1, requesting a larger version will make your `onUpgrade()` callback to be invoked where you can update the database file with the new column.

Comment: This is how things end up when someone is doing things like this: cursor.getString(4)

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is that the profileWeight is not in the database.
You need to increase the version of your database, so that the `onUpgrade` and `onCreate` method gets called and recreates your database with the profileWeight field.

The version is specified in this line

```
super(applicationcontext, "profiledatabase.db", null, 1);
```

try changing 1 for 2.